# algorithm for breaking single set of rows & columns into n rectangular fragments of random rows & random columns, randomly overlapping

Tags: algorithm, overlap, rectangles, random

I would like to convert a (given) single set D of rows and columns (e.g. spreadsheet or database table) of data into a randomly-generated set of N fragments for a given number n which is <= N, where the fragments also contain randomly-overlapping data. It would be preferable but is not necessary that n = N. Each data point (cell) in D must be contained in at least one fragment.

To clarify: "n" is a non-zero integer that the user provides that means "using D, give me back at least n fragments". "N" is the *actual number of fragments* that is returned. An acceptable algorithm is one that produces *at least n fragments*. For two acceptable algorithms X and Y, X is a better solution than Y if, all else equal, X yields an N that is closer to n than the N that Y yields.

In addition, data within any one row in any fragment must also be contained within one row in D. (Each fragment will also need to include an identifier column, such as Row ID or other column with unique values, but this should be trivial to add when the fragment is output). So for example, if D contains names and phone numbers along with other columns, then any fragment that has name and phone # in it should always have the right phone # associated with that row's name.

Generally speaking, if any column is present anywhere in a fragment, it must be present for every row of that fragment (e.g. if row 1 contains columns A, B, and C, then row 2 must contain those same columns), and the same goes for columns (e.g. if column B contains rows 4, 5, and 6, then every other column in the fragment must also contain rows 4, 5 and 6).

If N = 4, then the simplest approach I have come up with would be:

1. for each row, flip a coin. If heads, assign to fragment 1
2. for each row, flip a coin. If heads, assign to fragment 2
3. for each row, if it isn't assigned to either fragment 1 or fragment 2, flip a coin, and if heads, assign to fragment 1, else assign to fragment 2
4. repeat the above 3 steps for all columns. Now we have fragments 1 and 2, but these don't necessarily cover all the data in D. On to 3 and 4.
5. for each row, flip a coin. If heads, assign to fragment 3; else, if this row was assigned to fragment 2, but not to fragment 1, assign to fragment 3.
6. for each column, flip a coin. If heads, assign to fragment 3; else, if this column was assigned to fragment 2 but not to fragment 1, assign to fragment 3.
7. for each row, flip a coin. If heads, assign to fragment 4; else, if this row was already assigned to fragment 1, but not to fragment 2, assign to fragment 4.
8. for each column, flip a coin. If heads, assign to fragment 4; else, if this column was assigned to fragment 1 but not to fragment 2, assign to fragment 4

I believe this should yield 4 fragments that might look something like this, assuming that the rows and columns are reordered to be a contiguous block for fragment 1, and, to the extent possible without conflicting with that, to be contiguous for fragment 2 (green is where yellow + blue overlap):

[image: picture of D broken into overlapping fragments (1 and 2 are contiguous, 3 and 4 are not)]

However, this approach seems unwieldy to scale to higher values of N. Is there an easier way to generalize this for any value of n or N?

Comment: You say that there are N fragments, and that n must be <= N, but you don't say what n represents.

Comment: n is just an integer greater than zero, which is an input to the algorithm

Comment: What does it *mean*?  Why, for example, can I not simply say "Let n = 42"?

Comment: It means "I want to break dataset D into at least n fragments". And it would be better if it is possible to say "I want to break dataset D into *exactly* n fragments"

Comment: Given that your dataset D has N rows and M columns, and you want to break it up into at least n fragments where n is some integer > 0, is it possible that n > N, or n > M. And if not, why not split evenly (as possible) across a single dimension. For example, in your scenario when n = 4, why not split it into 4 groups of rows (each including all columns)?

Comment: The purpose of the exercise is to fragment D across both rows and columns with at least the given number n of fragments. If the columns of D are not fragmented, or the number of resulting fragments is less than n, then the purpose has not been achieved. Those are simply the given requirements that the algorithm must meet. @trincot sums it up well by defining a fragment as a "matrix that would result from removing some random columns and rows" from D.

Comment: A random solution could by coincidence be N fragments that are identical to the whole D, or less extreme: could have two identical fragments. Would this be rejected as an outcome?

Comment: But the description you just gave for n is the same as the description you gave for N in the question: "randomly-generated set of N fragments".  Are there two separate variables, n and N, or not?

Comment: Indeed the notion of both *n* and *N* is still unclear. It needs to be clearly stated what they are, what the difference is, and why you need both. Up til now I understood that *N* was an input, and that *n* would be the actual number of produced fragments in case the algorithm could not reach the count of *N*, but then later you wrote that *n* is an input to the algorithm... Confusing.

Comment: I'm not sure what is confusing: n is an input. N is an output (or derivation thereof). n < N is acceptable. the closer N is to n, the better (n = N is optimal). N < n is not acceptable.

Comment: @trincot, N fragments that are identical to D is fine if that is a *random* result. However, if that is a *probable* or *likely* or otherwise *clearly non-random* result, then it is not acceptable. By "random" I mean that, at least in appearance if not in fact, any possible fragment has an equal chance of being produced (when I say "in appearance", I mean that if someone runs the algorithm manually a bunch of times, it won't be obvious, without running in scale and measuring results, that it's not perfectly random).

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it!

Answer (score 1):

*--Edit (added Step 0)--*

Step 0. Randomly assign a probability-weight per fragment; use these weights when picking at random. You may require a different weight-structure for Step 1 and 2, respectively.

Step 1. Assign a set of random fragments per column (this is somehow similar to what @Jim proposed for each cell but on a column basis). So at the end, each column would belong to one or more fragments. It would be better if you assign at least 2 fragments per column; I explain below why I suggest this trick.

You should require a final check to ensure that all fragments present at least once and if not, try to add the missing fragments to random number of columns.

At this stage all fragments present, but they occupy every row.

Step 2. Scan each row and randomly delete some (not all of them) of the assigned fragments for this row. You cannot delete a fragment for which at least one cell on this row is represented from this fragment only. This is the reason why in Step 1, I suggest you pick at least 2 fragments per column, so you are always safe to delete at least one fragment per row. If you didn't do that, some of the fragments (those that were the only occupants on at least one column) may never be deleted and would keep occupying every row.

Perform a last check to ensure that you didn't completely erased any of the fragments.

Note 1. You can somehow control the overlapping density by playing with the probabilities of a) picking X fragments per column in Step 1 and b) deleting Y fragments per row in Step 2.

Note 2. Step 1 can run for rows and Step 2 for columns, maybe it's better to apply Step 1 on the larger dimension (to comply with the OPs comment).

Comment: Thank you, will try. My concern at first glance is that even when playing with the probabilities, the resulting distribution might end up getting more and more barbell-ed as the number of rows increases, and that with a reasonably large number of rows (say, 50,000), finding a probability that gets a seemingly random result (that isn't 0% or 100% overlapped) may require much trial and error (and/or exceed the computer's floating-point precision capabilities). Not that that would necessarily mean this didn't answer the question-- but would be hard to use in practice.

Answer (score 0):

One very simple way to do this would be to assign each cell a number from 1 to 15, inclusive. Each of the four bits corresponds to one of the fragments. So if bit 0 is set, the cell is part of fragment 1. If bit 1 is set, fragment 2, etc. So a cell assigned the number 1 would be in fragment 1. The cell with the number 9 (1001 in binary) would belong to fragments 1 and 4.

In the end you should end up with cells uniformly distributed among the four fragments.

For any number of fragments, `n`, pick a number between 1 and 2^n.

If there are special restrictions like "if cell(row, 1) is in fragment x, then cell(row, 5) must also be included in that segment," you can fix those up easily enough in post-processing with a single scan of the result set.

Comment: Considering the clarification I added to the question (starting with "Generally speaking"), following your suggestion, if n = 4, then with somewhat larger dimensions of D (say, 1000 x 200), seems to me that almost always, all 4 fragments would equal D, because if any cell in a given column (row) is in fragment X, then that entire column (row) must be in X.

Comment: @mwag: You're right. Let me give this a little more thought, and I'll post an update.

Answer (score 0):

**Given are:**

- D: a matrix with C columns, R rows, both dimensions numbered from 0 to D-1
- N: The desired number of "fragments", numbered from 0 to N-1. A fragment represents the matrix that would result from removing some random columns and rows from the original matrix.

**Required:**

Every cell in matrix D must be part of at least one fragment.

**Algorithm:**

```
fragments = empty array []
usedCols = array [0, .., 0] // C elements
usedRows = array [0, .., 0] // R elements

For f in 0..N-1: 
   Let fragments[f] = object {cols: array [0, .., C-1], rows: array [0, .., R-1]}

   Let deleteCount = random number between 0 and (C-1)
   For i in 1..deleteCount:
      Let index = random number between 0 and (C-i)
      Let excludedCol = fragments[f].cols[index]
      Let usedCols[excludedCol] = 1
      // "splice" the column out of the fragment, 
      // moving elements at higher indices to one lower index.
      Remove fragments[f].cols[index]

   Let deleteCount = random number between 0 and (R-1)
   For i in 1..deleteCount:
      Let row = random number between 0 and (R-i)
      Let excludedRow = fragments[f].rows[index]
      Let usedRows[excludedRow] = 1
      Remove fragments[f].rows[index]  // "splice"

// Assign rows/columns that have not been assigned 
// to any fragment to a random fragment:
For col in 0..C-1:
   If usedCols[col] == 0 Then
      Let f = random number between 0 and N-1
      Add col to fragments[f].cols
For row in 0..R-1:
   If usedCols[row] == 0 Then
      Let f = random number between 0 and N-1
      Add row to fragments[f].rows
```

At the end you'll have the fragments array with one array element per fragment, each defining a set of rows and a set of columns that belong to that fragment.

Comment: the number of rows & columns is not necessarily the same, which seems to be different from what your code assumes, though I don't think this matters for your answer. Also it seems like usedCols and usedRows should be initialized to [1..1] and set to 0 just prior to Remove calls. But whether I'm reading that or not I think I get the gist. However...

Comment: ... it seems to me the last 8 lines may be flawed. Consider if N = 4 and an oversimplified D consisting of 2 rows and 2 columns: call them A1, A2, B1 and B2 (a la Excel cell addresses). By chance, assume that frag 1 = frag 2 = A1, and frag 3 = frag 4 = B2 (A2 and B1 are not assigned to any frag). Then rows 1 and 2 are both used, and columns A and B are also both used, so the last 8 lines of code don't ever execute their Add statements, and A2 and B1 remain unrepresented by any fragment.